# How to print value name with R2wd

Tags: r, cpu-word

I have a frequency table:

```
freq.tab <- as.table(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))
```

I have assigned a function that would send this to Word using `R2wd`,

```
fun1 <- function(table){wdTable(table)}
fun1(freq.tab)
```

but I would like to add the table name `freq.tab` as a title.

Is there any way I can get `R` to print the table (or any value) name.

Basically, my output in Word should read something like:

> **freq.table** 
>   1 4 
>   2 5
>   3 6

Obviously, I could do this with `wdTitle("freq.table")`, but I need something this would fit within the function and be called without resorting to quoted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the argument supplied using as.character(substitute(whatever_you_wanted))

```
fun1 <- function(table){
    wdTitle(as.character(substitute(table)))    
    wdTable(table)
}
```